# navigation control in ionic provider

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, navigationcontroller

Im using navigation control in ionic provider whenever i triggered  the provider it shows the runtime error Cannot read property 'pop' of null

my code is

```
@Injectable()
export class ServerResponseProvider {
@ViewChild('myContent') navCtrl: NavController;

constructor(public http: Http, public alertCtrl: AlertController,  
protected injector: Injector, private app:App) {
console.log('Hello ServerResponseProvider Provider');
}

httpGetRes(url) {
return Observable.create(observer => {
  this.http.get(url)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log("response:", data);
      observer.next(data);
    }, (err) => {
      console.log("Your error : ", err);
      observer.error(err);
      if (err.status == 400) {
        this.alertC('Validation Error');
      } else if (err.status == 403) {
        this.alertC('Authorization error')
      } else if (err.status == 500) {
        this.alertC('Something went wrong try again later')
      }
    });
});
}

alertC(msg) {

let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: ' OOPS !!!!',
  subTitle: msg,
  buttons: [{
    text: 'ok',
    handler: () => {

     this.navCtrl.pop();
    }
  }]

});

alert.present(alert);

 }
}
```

i tried in many ways it wont works
thanks in advance